# How to assign values to levels in factors?

Tags: r

I want to assign values to the levels of a factor.
For example, if > 22 = mature, if <= 22 = adolescence. How can I do this?   My data is:

```
 x <- factor(c(13, 18, 35), levels = c("adolescence", "mature"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using just Base R this is a two step process.

Assuming your initial vector is numeric and not character strings (as shown above), use the `cut` function to define the initial factor equivalents.
Then use the "labels" option in the `factor` function to rename the factor levels.

```
factor(cut(c(13, 18, 35), breaks=c(0, 22, Inf)), labels = c("adolescence", "mature"))
#[1] adolescence adolescence mature     
#Levels: adolescence mature
```

*Edit*
As per Ben's comment, a simplified approach by adding the labels directly to the cut function:

```
cut(c(13, 18, 35), breaks=c(0, 22, Inf), labels = c("adolescence", "mature"))
```

Comment: Can this be a solution: `factor(if_else(c("13", "18", "35") <= 22, "adolescence","mature"))` ??

Comment: Dave2e indeed they are integers, I edited my question :).

Comment: you can specify `labels` directly within `cut()`: `cut(c(13, 18, 35), breaks=c(0, 22, Inf), labels = c("adolescence", "mature"))`

Answer (score 4):

a couple of alternatives:

If your data are

```
x <- c(13, 18, 35)
```

then

```
factor(ifelse(x<=22, "adolescence", "mature"))
## [1] adolescence adolescence mature     
## Levels: adolescence mature
factor(ifelse(x %in% c(13,18), "adolescence", "mature"))
## [1] adolescence adolescence mature     
## Levels: adolescence mature
```

If you already have a factor then converting them back to integers via `as.numeric(as.character(x))` is an option, or use `car::recode()` or `forcats::fct_collapse`